# Access User control Id used in aspx page in the user control code behind

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, user-controls

I have a user control registered and placed in a aspx page.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="Client" src="/PageLayout/Client.ascx"  %>
<uc1:Client id="IdClient1" runat="server"></uc1:Client>
```

I would like to access the id "IdClient1" in the codebehind of my user control Client. Can anybody tell how can i access it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In the code behind you can access the Control ID using `Me.ID` in VB or `this.ID` in C#.

In VB.NET

```
Me.ID
```

In C#

```
this.ID
```